# History.push replacing last part of path in url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react router v5, for one of my history.push calls it's replacing the last path section.

So instead of "/home/menu/allergens/newValue"

It navigates to "/home/menu/newValue"

It doesn't matter how many paths there are it always just replaces the last one?

All I'm using is history.push('modal/selectroute');

Why would this be?

Example code:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
export const Thing = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => history.push("modal/selectroute")}>
        navigate
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit smoosh-frost-yqh9ng]

Comment: Can you provide a code example of your problem?

Comment: @AryBarros navigate to /thing and then click the navigate button that appears https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-frost-yqh9ng?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Tried here with the example you gave (/home/menu/allergens/newValue) and it navigates to the same url.

Comment: The codesandbox demo doesn't reproduce the issue as you describe. The "navigate" button navigates to `"/model/selectroute"`.

Comment: @DrewReese Yep that is the issue, it should be navigating to /thing/modal/selectroute as the path supplied to history.push is relative right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it should be navigating to `"/thing/modal/selectroute"` as the path
> supplied to history.push is relative right?

No. `react-router-dom@5` routes and links don't use relative paths automatically like this like they do in RRDv6. In v5 you need to build the relative paths manually.

Example:

```
import { useHistory, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

export const Thing = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { url } = useRouteMatch(); // <-- get the current url
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        // prepend it to new target path
        onClick={() => history.push(`${url}/modal/selectroute`)}
      >
        navigate
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit history-push-replacing-last-part-of-path-in-url]

See the [RRDv5 Nesting demo](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, what confused me is there is a difference in behaviour between pushing 'modal' and '/modal', the latter is treated as an absolute path and the former behaves like a relative path but it's relative to the 'wrong' path location in this context

Answer (score 0):

In my case I missed (/) in front of the route. You should try doing it once.
For example: history.push("/modal/selectroute"). It worked in my case might work in this as well.